# Doctrine, @oneToMany, but only with activated field

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity for Company and an entity for Review. Company have multiple reviews.

When i call to `company->getReviews()`, i want that it return ONLY review that `isValidated` field is `TRUE`.

How can I do ? Which way is better ?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Company")
 */
class Company
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyAppBundle\Entity\Review", mappedBy="company")
     */
    protected $reviews;


    /**
     * Add reviews
     *
     * @param \ProSearch\ReviewBundle\Entity\Review $reviews
     * @return Company
     */
    public function addReview(\ProSearch\ReviewBundle\Entity\Review $reviews)
    {
        $this->reviews[] = $reviews;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove reviews
     *
     * @param \ProSearch\ReviewBundle\Entity\Review $reviews
     */
    public function removeReview(\ProSearch\ReviewBundle\Entity\Review $reviews)
    {
        $this->reviews->removeElement($reviews);
    }

    /**
     * Get reviews
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews;
    }

}

And the review entity :

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Review
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    protected $description;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyAppBundle\Entity\Company")
    */
    protected $company;



    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isValidated", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isValidated;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Company::$reviews` is a Doctrine `Collection`.

You can use the filter method on the collection. This yields a new collection with only validated reviews.

```
$companyObj->getReviews()->filter(function($review) { 
    return $review->isValidated();
});
```

Seeing as you've tagged this with Symfony as well. I'd advice against modifying `Company::getReviews()` because it is used in forms when using collections for example. It could also be quite confusing when a other developer wants all reviews from a Company. Calling `getReviews()` won't return the results the developer expects.

Answer (score 3):

The point is that company->getReviews() can be used by doctrine. You shoud create a new method :

```
public function getValidatedReviews() {

     $validatedReviews = array();

     foreach($this->getReviews() as $review {

         if($review->getIsValidated())
              $validatedReview[] = $review;
     }

     return $validatedReviews;
}
```